# Magento 2 cart keeps loading

Tags: magento2, product, cart, addtocart, shopping-cart

I have a weird bug.

Every time I add a product to my cart it shows as if it were loading.

[image]

However, it adds the product to the cart, if I switch to another page or reload the loading disappears and shows the amount in the cart.
Do you know what could it be?

This problem began when I moved the cart to top links.

Comment: Could you check the magento log and browser console?

Comment: There are no errors related to this case in my logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once got that problem when tried to overwrite `catalog-add-to-cart.js`. This file is located in `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\web\js`.

At `line 95` of that file: 
`$(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentLoading');` 
this will execute whenever **Add to cart** button is clicked.

From `line 153` to `line 156`:

    `if (res.minicart) {
        $(self.options.minicartSelector).replaceWith(res.minicart);
        $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentUpdated');
    }`

this block of code must be excuted to make the minicart status become normal. I'm using magento 2.3.2 CE. Hope that may help you.

Comment: thank you, but what should I do in that file?

Comment: In my situation, I tried to override this file in my module, and made the function return before the minicart can trigger the `'contentUpdated'` event. So if you also try to override this file like I did, take a look at this file in your module.

Comment: Open your browser's developer tool (press F12 in many browsers), go to network tab and try to add a product to cart. You will see something like `?sections=cart%2Cmessages&force_new_section_timestamp=true&_=1565400355595`. This is update cart request which contain updated minicart's html in server's response.

Comment: hello I think it works now, I moved $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentLoading'); function before  $(self.options.minicartSelector).replaceWith(res.minicart); and it seems to work.